# Puncturing the closed orientable surface of genus $g$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Prove that if we puncture the closed orientable surface of genus $g$, $k$ times, we have the following isomorphism $$M_{g, k} \cong \bigvee_{i=1}^{k+2g-1} S_i^1.$$

I know that we consider the fundamental polygon of the genus $g$ surface, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) (if you can) all answers you find useful **and** [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

There is no isomorphism there, but rather a *homotopy equivalence*.  Let us assume $k\geq 1$ since the statement is untrue for $k=0$.

Take the fundamental polygon of your genus-$g$ surface, which has $2g$ sides.  Arrange the $k$ punctures around a vertex, and draw $k-1$ nonintersecting lines ($1$-cells) from that vertex, around one one of the punctures, and back to the vertex; one of the vertices is left unencircled.  Retract the regions of the polygon for each of the $k$ punctures onto the neighboring drawn lines and polygonal borders.  The result is $2g$ circles from the $1$-skeleton of the surface and $k-1$ circles from those drawn lines.